# Unknown type name 'RazorpayCheckout'; did you mean 'RNRazorpayCheckout'?

Tags: react-native-ios, razorpay

I am using react-native integrating **Razorpay Payment Gateway**.

Version used : "react-native-razorpay": "**^2.2.4**"

Perfectly works with Android, APK built and tested. The same when I start building with XCODE. I see the following errors popping up [have attached screen] from xcode. When done with react-native using ***react-native run-ios --configuration=release*** [not sure if this is correct].. it again fails at Razorpay integration files [seen in the image]

Had followed the Razorpay docs and it says.. everything is autolinked;code does not work I am using Swift5 and XCode 12 [its the only version installed on mac][image]

Answer (score 1):

Issue was rectified by uninstalling and re-installing it again back. As per suggestion received from RazorPay team. This worked

Comment: I am facing the same issue. But your answer did not help.. Did you get to know anything other than this?

Comment: can you share the following
RN ver used. RP version used.. just to compare with mine and aswell share the error screen snapshot


in the mean time Manoj, can you do the following
1. remove RPay first & then the node modules, 
2. install nodemodule and then the RPay.. try linking with RP with RN [only this module]
3. pod install on ios, 
4. I think it should work

Do check with Android first.. if its working here.. it will work for sure in iOS too

Answer (score 0):

this is because of new apple M1 chip

do this step

[image: m1 solution] click on this link for solultion